# Insert PHP code via shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I wanted to insert a form with a line of PHP code via shortcode. I am wondering if it's allowed? Has anyone tried it? Take the following for example:

```
function get_form($atts) {
    return '<form method="post" action="">
            <input type="input" name="myinput" value=""></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="myvar" value="<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>">
            </form>';
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'get_form');
```

I hope it's clear now...

Comment: allowed? line of PHP code? what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$current_user` isn't declared in the scope of that function. You'd want to modify the code to be more like this:

```
function get_form($atts) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    return '<form method="post" action="">
            <input type="input" name="myinput" value=""></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="myvar" value="' . $current_user->ID . '">
            </form>';
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'get_form');
```

Comment: Of course, you should probably check to see if the user is even logged in at all with `if( is_user_logged_in() ){}` before assuming they are.

Answer (score 0):

no that wont work!

you need to return all of the value as string/html:

```
function get_form($atts) {
    return '<form method="post" action="">
            <input type="input" name="myinput" value=""></input>
            <input type="hidden" name="myvar" value="'.$current_user->ID.'">
            </form>';
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode', 'get_form');
```